# how to list directory with same string in its name in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh, busybox

I have msgbak-.tar.gz files in /var/log/ directory
how can i list all of them using `ls -lrt` command
i used following script but it doesn't work

`LGNAME="/var/log/msgbak"`
`touch $LGNAME-$(date)`
`$(ls -lrt $LGNAME*)`
OR
`$(ls -lrt {$LGNAME*})`

any help pointer/indicators please ?

I was trying following,
`LGNAME="/var/log/msgbak"`
`MAX_LOG_BACKUP=10`

`for taredfile in $(ls -lrt $LGNAME*)`
`do`
`if [ $(ls -lrt $LGNAME* | wc -l) -lt "$MAX_LOG_BACKUP" ]; then`
`echo`
`break;`
`fi`
`rm $taredfile`
`done`

This is what i was trying , i know its not bestway but i dont know what went wrong there.

Comment: Are you trying to list files *inside* the tarball?

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to achieve? It looks like you are trying to use the output for something, since you are wrapping the command inside `$()`.

Comment: i am not trying to list files inside tarball, i want to list all tar files with name "msgbak" present in that directory.

Comment: Ultimately i want to combine this with `wc -l` and get the number of such files. And then if number is more than 10 i want to delete the first one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works correctly for me to get the number of such files.

```
ls $LGNAME* | wc -l
```

If you wanted them sorted in reverse timestamp order, this should work fine:

```
ls -rt $LGNAME*
```

To answer the more general question, you could do something like this. I am not sure exactly what modifications you would need to make to make it work in a non-bash shell though.

```
LGNAME="/var/log/msgbak"
count=$(ls $LGNAME* | wc -l)

if [ "$count" -gt 10 ]; then
    ls $LGNAME* | head -n 1 | xargs rm
fi
```

Comment: whatever you suggested worked but i don't know what was wrong with my version, i have updated it in question.